# Merge conflict resolve

Tags: git

Before that i've had experience that i needed to merge my feature in two branches and everything was ok, but not so long ago i had a problems with that. Previously i checkout first branch and merged there my feature branch and after i checkout my second branch and merged there my feature. Everything was ok before, but when i've done it last time first branch was merged to second and it became a problem. So i try to understand was it my mistakes as i didn't checkout and merge correct branches or i just don't understand how merging works.

For example i have 3 branches.

```
dev
feature-1
master
```

if i checkout dev and merge there feature-1 branch and after that i checkout master and merge there feature-1 branch, will full dev branch be moved to master as one branch (dev+feature-1) or only feature-1 branch will be merged in master? Hope you understand me.

Comment: To answer your hypothetical example, only `feature-1` will then be merged into `master`, not `dev`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at rebase it might simplify things for you ( [git rebase doc](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) ) .

so:

1. rebase feature-1 on master :

> ```
> git checkout feature-1
> git rebase master
> ```

2. then from master merge feature-1 (this will do a fast forward merge)

> ```
> git checkout master 
> git rebase feature-1
> ```

3. now repeat with dev branch

> ```
> git checkout dev
> git rebase master
> git checkout master
> git rebase dev
> ```

this is going to be much cleaner (my opinion) and maybe easier to understand